# QGIS - Select Features by Value issues

Tags: qgis, relates

I have a point shapefile (parent) which is related to a CSV table (child) through a one-to-many relation (`Project` > `Properties` > `Relations` > `relationship strength`: `association`).
When I click on the command button, a mask like the one in QGIS [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#id15) appears, with the field names of the parent on the top and the child on the bottom.

What I need is to perform a very simple query: to select the points of the SHP that have a certain value in the related table.

First, I click the `Reset Form` button. I then set the first button on the right of a certain field to `Concatenate` and the second button to `Equal to (=)` and press the `Select Features` button. I don't get the right result, and an alert often says that there are no features with that value. But when I change the second button on the right of the field to `Contains`, some features are selected. I tried to check if it works because it recognizes only some letters, but this is not the case as `Equal to (=)` does not work even with distinct numbers. I checked how the fields from the CSV are read and they are read as strings. But strings should work well with `Equal to (=)` as well, as it is stated [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#id26). It does not work even checking the `Case sensitive` options.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong.